# How do I print in the middle of the screen?

Tags: python

For example,

```
print "hello world"
```

in the middle of screen instead of beginning? Sample output would be like:

```
                                   hello world
```

Comment: Is this on a terminal, or on a GUI window?

Answer (score 13):

Python 3 offers [`shutil.get_terminal_size()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.get_terminal_size), and you can use [`str.center`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.center) to center using spaces:

```
import shutil

columns = shutil.get_terminal_size().columns
print("hello world".center(columns))
```

<del>If you’re not using Python 3, use [`os.get_terminal_size()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.get_terminal_size) instead.</del>

As @br1ckb0t mentions, this isn’t available conveniently in Python 2. Rather than using a less convenient way, though, I’d suggest switching to Python 3 instead.

Comment: Wow, never heard of that. Looks neat. :)

Comment: @minitech as far as I can tell, `os.get_terminal_size()` is Python 3.0+, and `shutil.get_terminal_size()` is 3.3+, so this wouldn't work in Python 2

Comment: @minitech no problem. Only thing - you can do this easily in Python 2 with subprocess: `subprocess.check_output(['stty', 'size']).split()[1]`. No need to switch to Python 3.

Comment: @br1ckb0t: That’s not really portable, though; you’d have to wrap it in an equivalent to `get_terminal_size`. Possible, but not really convenient.

Comment: @minitech good point. But I think it's worth having in there as an option. I put in an edit - feel free to reject it.

Answer (score 2):

The same way you did it by hand: add extra spaces.

If you mean to actually know something about the geometry of the display, you'll have to appeal to a library for such things. e.g. the [`curses`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html) module.

> The curses module provides an interface to the curses library, the de-facto standard for portable advanced terminal handling.

Comment: Note: curses also allows cursor positioning; with a curses-based approach one doesn't need to pad with spaces.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a terminal window, do exactly what you did. If you want consistency, you can try use tab tokens (`\t`) to keep everything in line. Otherwise, follow Hurkyl's answer about using the `curses` module.

```
>>> print "\t\t\t Hello World!"
             Hello World! # Output
```

Answer (score 2):

See @minitech's answer for a good way to do this on Python 3, but on Python 2, this can be done with `subprocess` (at least on OS X):

```
import subprocess

def print_centered(s):
    terminal_width = int(subprocess.check_output(['stty', 'size']).split()[1])
    print s.center(terminal_width)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `center()` to put text in the middle.

For example:

```
str = "Hello World";
print str.center(20)
```

Answer (score 0):

This way you can print leading spaces:

```
   print ' '*5, 'hello'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a helper function:

```
import operator

SCREEN_WIDTH = 80
centered = operator.methodcaller('center', SCREEN_WIDTH)

print(centered("hello world"))
```

Answer (score 0):

A version of get_termial_size that should work for python2, tested but not  extensively on ubuntu:

```
from collections import namedtuple

def get_terminal_size():
    import struct
    from fcntl import ioctl
    from termios import TIOCGWINSZ
    Res = namedtuple("terminal_sizes", field_names=["columns","lines"])
    try:
        term = struct.unpack('hhhh', ioctl(0, TIOCGWINSZ, '\000' * 8))
    except IOError:
        return Res(24, 80)
    return Res(term[0], term[1])



In [23]: print("Hello world".center(get_terminal_size().columns))
                              Hello world
```